# How can measurements of health properties be modeled in a class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a User class that can "measure" some parameters associated to a date and input them in an application. So 1 User -> many parameters of many types associated to many dates (many measurements). The parameters types are fixed and can be both numeric or strings, e.g: weight, height, calories intake, some strings... which are represented as an enumeration.

Now my main problem is: does the fact that the parameters can be of different datatypes (numbers or strings) mean that the general parameter type has to have specialisations for the two subgroups of parameters? Or is the datatype for each type of parameter implied in the type itself? (e.g. a "weight" implies it should be a number)

[image: diagram]

How can the "Parameter" class be represented in a correct way considering that:

- it can be both numerical or a string
- there is also a superuser class that can add parameters for a specific user
- the parameters the superuser can input are some of the ones the normal user can PLUS some other parameters exclusive to the superuser (say: fat body mass) so there is not a 1-1 correspondence
- the numerical parameters have other additional attributes that can be modified by the superuser (for example: limit weight)
- the superuser supposedly should be able to add "notes" for some parameters

My confusion stems from the fact that I have no background in OOP programming and i can't find any similar examples online. I just need an input towards the right direction to go to. Is the pictured diagram correct? And why it most likely isn't? The problem as of now would be how to implement the fact that the superuser can also add notes to *some* parameters.

Do I:

1. create a single parameter class with the enumeration type as attribute which automatically implies the datatype of the input e.g weight = number?
2. create two subclasses for each User, e.g. UserParameters and SuperUserParameters, although some parameters overlap?
3. leave it as is with some adjustments?
4. other better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to propose using an improved terminology. Since your app is about (health) property measurements, I'll replace your class name "Parameter" with `Measurement`.

The following model should satisfy all of your requirements (except the one discussed below):

[image]

Notice that the two subclasses `UserProperty` and `SpecialProperty` simply define a partitioning of `Property`. They can be eliminated by adding an enumeration attribute `propertyCategory` to the `Property` class, having `USER_PPROPERTY` and `SPECIAL_PPROPERTY` as its enum literals.

The only requirement, which is not yet covered, is

> the numerical parameters have other additional attributes that can be
>   modified by the superuser (for example: limit weight)

This needs further carification. If these "other additional attributes" form a fixed set, then they can be modeled as further attributes of the `Property` class.

Comment: Thank you this gave me a bit of insight but a few things aren't clear to me yet. The general property class essentially tracks the data type (number/string) and the specializations are the specific parameters (weight, etc) for each user, correct? The thing I'm not sure about is what attributes the UserProperty and SpecialProperty would have? Would two enumerations be okay? The other thing is about the relationship between Property and Measurement, shouldn't it be an aggregation?

Comment: The additional attributes are fixed (they are all limits to the parameters) and have default values that can be "personalized" by each SuperUser for any User. I thought of the pre-fixed default values as attributes to the Parameter (Property) class and of the additional changes by the SuperUser as a separate class, that would store the parameter, the new limit, the date and the relationship to the User and would override the default settings. Could that work or is a relationship between SuperUser and Property enough?

Comment: The two subclasses `UserProperty` and `SpecialProperty` simply define a partitioning of `Property`. They can be eliminated by adding an enumeration attribute `propertyCategory` to the `Property` class, having `USER_PPROPERTY` and `SPECIAL_PPROPERTY` as its enum literals.

Comment: The relationship between Property and Measurement is an association. An aggregation, in UML, is a special type of association with the intended meaning of being a part-whole relationship where parts can be shared (are not exclusive). But this is rather of philosophical and not of technical significance and has no implications on coding.

Comment: When the additional attributes of numerical properties are `limit` and `defaultValue`, then simply add these two ettributes to the `Property` class. If you need a history of the defualt value changes, then you need an additional class. Otherwise, you could simply add two attributes: `initialDefaultValue` and `actualDefaultValue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should do that on UML level at all. You are going into memory management/overlays. And those are implementation details you should not take care of. Rather you are dealing with `HeartRate` and `Weight` as distinct objects. They will not have a common "value", which is just some memory allocation. They are what they are and whether you need a string or a number is some property of the distinct business objects.